# JQuery basics about child and parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code for a 2 level menu goes like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked navbar-fixed" id="side-menu">
    <li class="active ">
        <a href="index.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click here to go to home page">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home 
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="xyz">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Level 1
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right">X</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-header">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comMenu">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw"></i> Level 1
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right"> X </span>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav nav-second-level nav-stacked collapse " id="comMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-exchange fa-fw"></i> Level 2.1
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i> Level 2.2
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-fw"></i> Level 2.3
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Now I want to select the span with `id=destruct`, which is at level 1 and on click remove entire html in the li (including the second level ul tag). You must have got it that I am trying to make a `"X"`, upon clicking which the menu item and any sub-menu item deletes.

However, I need your help in selecting the correct elements. For only Level 1 menu, the following jQuery code works:

```
$(".destruct").click(function(e){
         $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

What could be the correct selector for Level 2 menu? I tried a few options like nth children and all, but cant seem to get it right.

Comment: what should happen when you click on a 2nd level li item? should there be a .destruct span in a 2nd level li item also?

Comment: Yes. that would be nice to have as well. Didn't really think about it.

Comment: The second ul exists *after* the parent, which is the `<a>` tag, so it survives. You could put the click listener on the top level `<li>` and delegate so you can just remove the first ul found underneath.

Comment: @Juank  Wow. i have been struggling for quite some time. But the following code works:    $(this).parent().parent().remove();  Now i am wondering, if there is better approach after what Richard just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this: li > a > span, so if you start in the span, you should look at the parent of the parent, of what is best, search for the closest "li" (because yo can change your html structure inside li's without tuch your jquery code). With a change in the html (add the x in all levels) you can get what @Juan suggested:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked navbar-fixed" id="side-menu">
    <li class="active ">
        <a href="index.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click here to go to home page">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home 
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="xyz">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Level 1
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right">X</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-header">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comMenu">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw"></i> Level 1
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right"> X </span>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav nav-second-level nav-stacked collapse " id="comMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-exchange fa-fw"></i> Level 2.1
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right">X</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i> Level 2.2
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right">X</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-fw"></i> Level 2.3
            <span class="destruct" style="float:right">X</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>

$(function () {
  $(".destruct").click(function() {
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();//first option
         $(this).closest('li').remove();//best option
  });
});
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGaGby

Comment: Yes, if you check above in the comments, I had that figured out. but @Richard Carls above got me thinking, is there a better approach?

Comment: I really don't understand the Richar Carls comment. I think that the approach works weell for your needs. I updated the answer and the codepen to include the @Juank suggestion